# MPI4PY - Scatter Numpy array containing various data types

Tags: python-3.x, mpi4py

I have a numpy array contain various data types (strings, integers, etc.)

I am trying to scatter the numpy array across 20 nodes:

sample data is extracted from a CSV file and then put into a numpy array called "data".

```
data = numpy.array(sample_data)
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
N = data.size

if rank == 0:
    print ("Application Will be Scattering: \n\n", data)
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n") 
    sendbuf = numpy.array(data)

    ave, res = divmod(sendbuf.size, size)
    count = [ave + 1 if p < res else ave for p in range(size)]
    count = numpy.array(count)

    displ = [sum(count[:p]) for p in range (size)]
    displ = numpy.array(displ)

else:
    sendbuf = None
    count = numpy.zeros(size, dtype=numpy.int)
    displ = None

comm.Bcast(count, root=0)
recvbuf = numpy.zeros(count[rank])

comm.Scatterv([sendbuf, count, displ, MPI.DOUBLE], recvbuf, root=0)
print("Process %d At Node %s Recieved: " % (rank, name), recvbuf)
```

the output is always in integers?

```
Process 17 At Node KPie01 Received:  [0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 1.01855798e-312 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a conversion error. I was trying to take an array of objects and parse them into a numpy array before executing my MPI4PY code... this was simply resolved by reading the data from the CSV file straight into pandas.